# Определить часть речи

Tags: морфология, части-речи

Добрый вечер. Подскажите, пожалуйста, в предложении: "В комментариях к этому посту появились десятки вариантов заголовков новостей, которые могли бы появиться, ОСТАНЬСЯ с нами очередь на Серова надолго". 
Какая часть речи-"ОСТАНЬСЯ"? 
Это глагол, но  не повелительное наклонение. Как объяснить какая это часть речи?

Comment: Часть речи - глагол, Вы же сами пишете. Что тут объяснять?

Comment: Так "появились" или "могли бы появиться"? Текст неясен.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Останься - глагол повелительного наклонения в значении условного: если бы осталась.

Такое встречается, правда, достаточно редко.При разборе так и пишут: по форме повелительное наклонение, по смыслу-условная модальность (обозначает возможную реальность). Модальность формы и содержания не совпадает.

Answer (score 5):

Да, это глагол и наклонение - повелительное, но в роли условного. В корпусной грамматике это называется императивом условия. Там есть несколько примеров употребления для разных функционалов, вот начало.

> 4.8.6. Императив условия
>
> Императив условия – наиболее частотное из непрямых употреблений
>   императива (см. п.5. Статистика). Как правило, такой императив
>   обозначает контрфактивное условие, то есть описывает ситуацию, которая
>   никогда не имела места и не будет иметь место:
>
> (187) Проживи он еще два-три года, и его, скорее всего, ждала бы
>   судьба О.Э. Мандельштама и Н.И. Вавилова. [«Вопросы психологии»
>   (2004)]

http://rusgram.ru/%D0%98%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2#486

Дальнейший анализ затруднен, поскольку контекста недостаточно 
для понимания, является ли это условием нереальным или возможным, т.к.  "могли бы появиться" при том, что "появились", допускает разные прочтения.